# MPMoviePlayerController Covers All Other Views

Tags: iphone, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, avcapturesession

I am attempting to play a movie fullscreen, with an AVCaptureSession showing the front camera in a smaller view in the corner (think FaceTime).  If I comment out the code for playing the video, the FrontCamera Displays perfectly in the corner where I placed the UIView containing it.  If I leave the code to run as is, only the video shows, covering up the UIView containing the subLayer for the AVCapture.  One other subissue, is the controls for the movie, and timeline bar show, and I would like to know if there is a way to disable that in the MPMoviePlayerController.  Here is the code I am using:

```
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

CALayer *viewLayer = self.vImagePreview.layer;
NSLog(@"viewLayer = %@", viewLayer);

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
captureVideoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.vImagePreview.bounds;
[self.vImagePreview.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

AVCaptureDevice *device = [self frontFacingCameraIfAvailable];

NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
if (!input) {
    // Handle the error appropriately.
    NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
}
[session addInput:input];

[session startRunning];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *proud = [[documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"proud"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:selectedCountry];

NSURL  *movieURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:proud] retain];
self.player =

[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: movieURL];

[player prepareToPlay];

player.allowsAirPlay = NO;
player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;    
self.player.view.frame = self.view.frame;

[self.view addSubview: player.view];
[self.player setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

// ...

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:player];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(exitedFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:player];


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayerWillExitFullscreen:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification
                                           object:player];


[player play];
```

vImagePreview is an IBOutlet UIView property declared in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views will be displayed with the last added on top by default.  So when the code adds the movie player view:

```
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
```

It's on top of everything else and has a frame the full size of the parent's bounds.  If there's some subview that you'd like to remain on top, you can either put it back on top after you add the movie player...

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:otherSubview];
```

.. or place the movie player underneath it to begin with...

```
[self.view insertSubview:player.view belowSubview:otherSubview];
```

There are [quite a few other methods available](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) to control the view hierarchy.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  I ended up inserting it below the other subview.